# Netplan ignoring .network file

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have Ubuntu 18.04 (downgraded to server) installed and can't get internet working on my Ethernet adapter.

Sorry for no files content pasted but I'm writing from different PC. I'm attaching screenshot with everything important (IMO) below.

Got `*.yaml` in `/etc/netplan` set to DHCP and `*.network` in `/run/systemd/network` looks fine. I have no IPv4 IP shown by `ip addr`. `networkctl` shows adapter sometimes in `n/a` and sometimes in `degraded` states. `Setup` state is always `unmanaged`.

When restarting `systemd-networkd` with `debug` log level I can see that it ignores `/run/systemd/network/*.network` file "because it's not a regular file with suffix .netdev".

Please take a look at the screenshot representing the log file:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBNBS.jpg)

I'm not an advanced linux user so kindly be explanatory in your responses :) 
Please let me know if you need more information to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device section listed in your netplan yaml is enp0s3, but the device name on your system is enp3s0.  By default unless you add a match: rule, the device section must have the same name as your network device.

Comment: So embarrassing. You are 100% right. There was a typo in yaml file. I fixed that and removed match macaddress section and it still works. Thank you :)

Comment: Holly f@%ing cow I just encountered the same identical issue as my enp3s0 was misspelled exactly the same way. I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong until I found this post and checked spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Adding match macaddress to my `*.yaml` file helped in my case:

```
match: 
  macaddress: "ADAPTER_MAC_ADDRESS"
```

I also, along, had an issue that the adapter was `DOWN` right after a reboot. Match macaddress solved that issue too.